# Signed pdf with selfsigned digital id in PdfBox is blank

Tags: pdfbox

I'm trying to sign existing pdf document with pdfbox. My class implements `SignatureInterface` interface, uses bouncycastle as provider and selfsigned cert stored in .jks file. But in output I get a blank page. What's wrong with my code?

```
public class CreateSignature implements SignatureInterface {

private PrivateKey privateKey;
private Certificate[] cert;

private CreateSignature(KeyStore keyStore, String certPassword) throws KeyStoreException, UnrecoverableKeyException, NoSuchAlgorithmException {
    privateKey = (PrivateKey) keyStore.getKey("1", certPassword.toCharArray()); // "1" - alias default name
    cert = keyStore.getCertificateChain("1");
}

@Override
public byte[] sign(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException {

    byte[] c = IOUtils.toByteArray(inputStream);

    List<Certificate> certList = new ArrayList<>();
    certList.add(cert[0]);

    try {
        Store certs = new JcaCertStore(certList);

        CMSSignedDataGenerator gen = new CMSSignedDataGenerator();
        org.bouncycastle.asn1.x509.Certificate certificate = org.bouncycastle.asn1.x509.Certificate.getInstance(ASN1Primitive.fromByteArray(cert[0].getEncoded()));

        ContentSigner sha1Signer = new JcaContentSignerBuilder("SHA256WithRSA").build(privateKey);

        gen.addSignerInfoGenerator(new JcaSignerInfoGeneratorBuilder(new JcaDigestCalculatorProviderBuilder().build()).build(sha1Signer, new X509CertificateHolder(certificate)));
        gen.addCertificates(certs);

        CMSTypedData  msg = new CMSProcessableByteArray(c);
        CMSSignedData signedData = gen.generate(msg,false);

        return signedData.getEncoded();

    } catch (CertificateEncodingException | OperatorCreationException | CMSException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }

}

public static byte[] signPdfDocument(PDDocument document) throws KeyStoreException, CertificateException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, IOException, UnrecoverableKeyException {
    String keystorePassword = AppVars.getPdfCertificationKeystorePass();
    String adobeDigitalIDPassword = AppVars.getPdfCertificationAdobePass();
    KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
    ks.load(CreateSignature.class.getResourceAsStream("/pdf/certificate/SelfSignedCert.jks"), keystorePassword.toCharArray());

    CreateSignature singing = new CreateSignature(ks, adobeDigitalIDPassword);

    return singing.doSign(document);
}

private byte[] doSign(PDDocument document) throws IOException {
    PDSignature signature = new PDSignature();
    signature.setFilter(PDSignature.FILTER_ADOBE_PPKLITE);
    signature.setSubFilter(PDSignature.SUBFILTER_ADBE_PKCS7_DETACHED);
    signature.setName("name");
    signature.setLocation("location");
    signature.setReason("reason");

    signature.setSignDate(Calendar.getInstance());

    document.addSignature(signature, this);
    ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    document.saveIncremental(out);

    document.close();
    return out.toByteArray();
}
```

}

Comment: What version are you using? Can you upload the unsigned and the signed PDF? Is there any log output coming?

Comment: @Tilman pdfbox v.2.0.3. https://www.dropbox.com/s/7w4r83f10cp29tb/Invoice_signed.pdf?dl=0
https://www.dropbox.com/s/9jepi0psv600z1l/Invoice_unsigned.pdf?dl=0 ,      no log output

Comment: @Tilman https://www.dropbox.com/s/mvllf0txlz582ue/Invoice_unsigned_1.pdf?dl=0   without signature adding

Comment: Thanks. I tried signing the source PDF with the CreateSignature example and it worked fine. Your code does not show how the PDDocument is created. Are you changing stuff in your document without saving and then do the signing? That would not work. Or could it be that you're signing a different file than you think? Your "signed" file is much smaller than the unsigned file, which should never happen. If you (or I) can't find the cause, I'd recommend you start with the example and then modify step by step.

Comment: You're right, I tried to sign unsaved document. We build our accessible (tagged) pdf based on predefined empty file created in Acrobat with tab order set to "S" - [one](https://taggedpdf.com/508-pdf-help-center/tab-order-entry-in-page-with-annotations-not-set-to-s/) of the "tagged" requirements (i  did not find possibility to set it dinamically with pdfbox). So without  saving I tried to sign this empty file. Great Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As discussed in the comments - the cause was that the document was built in the application itself after loading, and not loaded from a PDF file (or stream). The incremental signing would not identify these changes as such, so the result was the PDF at the time of loading, plus a signature that was not shown, probably becaus the document did not even have a page. What gave it away was that the signed PDF was much smaller than the unsigned PDF.

The solution is

- Create your PDF, create your content
- Save it
- Close it
- Reload the PDF and sign it.